# Printf command not printing when new code to find common divisors added.

Tags: c++, loops, greatest-common-divisor

I had an assignment in college, to take in as input, two numbers and to use brute force to obtain their individual divisors, store them in arrays and then print them. Following which we were asked to obtain their common divisors using a comparison between the two arrays and, create an array which contained the common divisors and to then print them.

The code below worked just fine

```
int main() {
int n1, n2, i, j, n, k, l, m, u, h, test ;
int divisors1[100] ;
int divisors2[100] ;
int common_div[100] ;
int up_limit, low_limit ;

printf("Enter an integer") ;
scanf("%d", &n1) ;
printf("Enter an integer") ;
scanf("%d", &n2) ;

for(i = 1, j = 0, k = 0; i <= n ; i++){
if(n1 % i == 0){
    divisors1[j] = i ;
    j++ ;
}
if(n2 % i == 0){
    divisors2[k] = i ;
    k++ ;
}
}
// printf("The divisors of %d are ", n1);
for(l = 0 ; l < j ; l++){
 printf("%d ", divisors1[l]) ;
}
printf("\n") ;
// printf("The divisors of %d are ", n2) ;
for(l = 0; l < k ; l++){
printf("%d ", divisors2[l]) ;
}
}
```

However after I added this new block of quote no code seems to be working. Neither the one above nor the one below. I add the code right after the end of the first part of the code.

```
up_limit = 0 ;
low_limit = 0 ;
if(j > k){
up_limit = j ;
low_limit = k ; 
}else{
up_limit = k ;
low_limit = j ;
}

if(up_limit == j){
for(m = 0; m < up_limit ; m++){
test = divisors1[m] ;
for(h = 0, u = 0 ; h < low_limit; h++){
    printf("%d", divisors2[h]) ;
    if(test == divisors2[h]){       
        common_div[u] = divisors2[h] ;
    u++ ;
    }   
}
}
}else{
 for(m = 0; m < up_limit ; m++){
test = divisors2[m] ;
for(h = 0, u = 0 ; h < low_limit; h++){
    printf("%d", divisors1[h]) ;
    if(test == divisors1[h]){   
        common_div[u] = divisors2[h] ;
    u++ ;
    }   
}
}

}
printf("The common divisors are \n") ;  
for(i = 0; i < u ; i++){ 
printf("%d ", common_div[u]) ;
}
```

My main question is why does printf work erratically in such cases.
Here is a sample output after I added the code

```
Enter an integer 345
Enter an integer345

The common divisors are
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program exhibits [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The problem is here:

```
  for (i = 1, j = 0, k = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if (n1 % i == 0) {
    ...
```

the variable `n` has never been initialized (IOW you never put anything in it), it contains therefore an intdeterminate value. If the program works, it is by pure coincidence.

Unless you don't fix this, it is pointless to investigate why the program doesn't work anymore once you have added your additional code.

A possible fix for your program is this:

Replace this part:

```
for(i = 1, j = 0, k = 0; i <= n ; i++){
if(n1 % i == 0){
    divisors1[j] = i ;
    j++ ;
}
if(n2 % i == 0){
    divisors2[k] = i ;
    k++ ;
}
}
```

with this:

```
  for (i = 1, j = 0; i <= n1; i++) {
    if (n1 % i == 0) {
      divisors1[j] = i;
      j++;
    }
  }

  for (i = 1, k = 0; i <= n2; i++) {
    if (n2 % i == 0) {
      divisors2[k] = i;
      k++;
    }
  }
```

Some more hints:

- replace all variable names such as `j`, `k` etc. by meaningful names such as `nbdivisors1`, `nbdivisors2` etc. One exception is `i` whic is often used as loop index.
- [indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) your code correctly
- learn how to use your debugger. This allows you to execute your code step by step and to inspect the contents of variables. It's a great time saver.

**Disclaimer:** there may be more problems in the second part

Answer (score -1):

You are printing common_div[u]. Maybe you wanna print common_div[i]? because the array at index u doesn't have any value.

```
printf("The common divisors are \n") ;  
for(i = 0; i < u ; i++){ 
printf("%d ", common_div[u]) ;
}
```